# Join within date range

Tags: r

I have two `DF` and I would like to group them together, however I have to check if the data is within a date range. My first DF:

```
ID <- c(111,222,333,444,555,666)
DT_START_HOSP <- as.Date(c('2021/01/07','2021/01/11','2021/01/21','2021/01/21','2021/01/21','2021/01/22'))
DT_END_HOSP <- as.Date(c('2021/01/10','2021/01/20','2021/01/25','2021/02/01','2021/01/29','2021/02/02'))
HOSP <- data.frame(ID,DT_START_HOSP,DT_END_HOSP)
```

My second `DF`:

```
ID <- c(1010,1010,1010,222,222,5050,5050,666,666)
DT_START_OUT <- as.Date(c('2021/01/01','2021/01/11','2021/01/30','2021/01/02','2021/01/15','2021/03/15','2021/04/20','2021/01/25','2021/01/28'))
DT_END_OUT <- as.Date(c('2021/01/01','2021/01/11','2021/01/30','2021/01/02','2021/01/15','2021/03/20','2021/04/20','2021/01/25','2021/01/30'))
OUT <- data.frame(ID,DT_START_OUT,DT_END_OUT)
```

I want to select only the “ID's” that are within the range of the columns `(DT_START_HOSP and DT_END_HOSP)` compared to the columns `(DT_START_OUT and DT_END_OUT)`. Thus, the result I expect is:

```
ID <- c(111,222,333,444,555,666,666)
DT_START_HOSP <- as.Date(c('2021/01/07','2021/01/11','2021/01/21','2021/01/21','2021/01/21',' 2021/01/22','2021/01/22'))
DT_END_HOSP <- as.Date(c('2021/01/10','2021/01/20','2021/01/25','2021/02/01','2021/01/29',' 2021/02/02','2021/02/02'))
DT_START_OUT <- as.Date(c('','2021/01/15','','','','2021/01/25','2021/01/28'))
DT_END_OUT <- as.Date(c('','2021/01/15','','','','2021/01/25','2021/01/30'))
HOSP <- data.frame(ID,DT_START_HOSP,DT_END_HOSP,DT_START_OUT,DT_END_OUT)
```

However, I used this code ([Join tables by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958975/join-tables-by-date-range)), but it didn't work. See the result

```
library(sqldf)
RESULT <- sqldf("select * from HOSP
                left join OUT
                on HOSP.DT_START_HOSP between OUT.DT_START_OUT and OUT.DT_END_OUT")
```

[image]

Is it possible to perform this join respecting a date range?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 dataframes if value within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934361/merge-2-dataframes-if-value-within-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is not as simple as "between", since it appears that you want any kind of overlap, whether a superset or otherwise. For that, we need a slightly different query (and should include `ID` on the left-join as well, I'm inferring).

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  select h.*, o.DT_START_OUT, o.DT_END_OUT
  from HOSP h
    left join OUT o on h.ID = o.ID
      and h.DT_START_HOSP < o.DT_END_OUT
      and h.DT_END_HOSP > o.DT_START_OUT")
#    ID DT_START_HOSP DT_END_HOSP DT_START_OUT DT_END_OUT
# 1 111    2021-01-07  2021-01-10         <NA>       <NA>
# 2 222    2021-01-11  2021-01-20   2021-01-15 2021-01-15
# 3 333    2021-01-21  2021-01-25         <NA>       <NA>
# 4 444    2021-01-21  2021-02-01         <NA>       <NA>
# 5 555    2021-01-21  2021-01-29         <NA>       <NA>
# 6 666    2021-01-22  2021-02-02   2021-01-25 2021-01-25
# 7 666    2021-01-22  2021-02-02   2021-01-28 2021-01-30
```

(Thank you for fixing your data from the previous question and the first draft of this one. For the record, you may want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319606/3358272), some handy code that deals well with vectors of dates in inconsistent/different formats.)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I really had done something wrong. I'm building code to try to identify scams and I believe this will help me.